# Command failed due to signal:Segmentation fault:11

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to retrieve NSMutableArray from NSUserdefaults. The code gives me an exception:

```
if let chatUsersJidArray = KUtility.getUserDefault(key: KChatUsersJid) as? NSMutableArray
```

Gives me error:

```
[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Later i used below code:

```
if let chatUsersJidArray = KUtility.getUserDefault(key: KChatUsersJid).mutableCopy() as? NSMutableArray
```

Then `"Command failed due to signal:Segmentation fault:11"`. Any help appreciated, i got many other solution but didn't got one which uses mutable copy.

Comment: Try to change the `Swift Compiler` - `Optimization Level` to `Fast, Whole Module Optimization` instead of `None` or build for configuration Release to isolate the root of the issue.

Comment: Not worked, same error happens

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: user defaults returns an immutable array and it's impossible in Swift to cast to mutable Foundation collection types. Don't use `NSMutable...` in Swift at all.

Comment: I need to remove item from it, its not possible in case of NSarray

Answer (score 0):

Try using native Swift `Array` struct. By defining it as a `var`, it automatically becomes mutable

```
if var chatUsersJidArray = KUtility.getUserDefault(key: KChatUsersJid) as? [ARRAY_TYPE] {
    // use the chatUsersJidArray
}
```

Comment: I need to remove item from it, its not possible in case of NSarray

Comment: If you use the native Swift `Array` struct as a `variable` (as I showed in the answer), you'll be able to add and remove objects from the array @user2702179

Answer (score -1):

Getting value directly from `NSUserDefaults` will not return `Mutable` object. For that, you need to grab `mutableCopy`

```
if let chatUsersJidArray = KUtility.getUserDefault(key: KChatUsersJid) as? NSArray {
    var arrChatJidMutable = chatUsersJidArray.mutableCopy()
    //Now you can manipulate this array. Add / Remove / Update
}
```